# Counting number of images in a directory: not working

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am running Python 2.7.6 on Windows 7. I have a directory at `C:/Data/Images` which contains a number of JPEG images. So, I navigate to `C:/Data` in Command Prompt, and then run the Python shell by entering `python`. Then, I enter the following:

```
print len([f for f in os.listdir('Images') if os.path.isfile(f)])
```

And this returns `0`, even though I know that there are several images in `C:/Data/Images`.

Why is this?

Answer (score 2):

[`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) returns a list of filenames (wihtout directory path part). You need to join the directory name with filename.

```
[f for f in os.listdir('Images') if os.path.isfile(os.path.join('Images', f))]
```